# Problem in loading or registering SQLite JDBC driver

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, libraries, dbconnection

I have provided all screenshots that I believe would help with this question.
I have been given a jar along with zipped files that allow me to simply add the jar to a created project that I have started. Once I run the file it gives me the following error as if I haven't added the jar correctly. However, as shown I believe I have done what is necessary for it to operate. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I forgot to add the file at the end of the path..
I'll leave this questions incase anyone else has a brainfart too.

```
"Users/mattgranado/Documents/UTPB/information_systems_and_security/addressBook.db"
```